cant make realtek audio codec
i recently dualbooted my windows with kubuntu and now that i have installed discord on it my friend told me that i sound like a robot and he can hear me 2 times. So i decided to download realtek audio codec. (i have it on my windows also i have a b650 gaming x so it should work). I downloaded it got to the part to make so i made it and it gives me.
also i have downloaded the requirements tru the requirements txt. I am new to linux so more detailed explanention of the fix would be appreciated.
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:243: archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-36-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:167: compile] Error 2


Are you sure the source you downloaded is appropriate for your kernel? Please [edit] your question to include a link if possible.
